# Why op amp output impedance depends on current output?

Tags: operational-amplifier, impedance

Here is the following component [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm324b.pdf?ts=1687508453686&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FLM324B) and here is the output impedance :

[image]

Why op amp output impedance depends on current output ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]

Transconductance and current gain of transistors varies a lot with collector/drain current.

For bipolars, transconductance is proportional to collector current except at the extremes, when the transistor is on the verge of turning off, or under more current than it can handle. Current gain also follows an inverted-U shape, it reaches a maximum in the range where the transistor is intended to be used, and decreases both at very low and very high collector currents.

For MOSFETs, although the physics behind it are completely different, effects are quite similar for transconductance: it is low in the subthreshold region where it barely conducts, and limited at very high current. FETs don't have DC current gain but they do have gate capacitance and transconductance: to get the desired AC drain current, gate current is necessary, and it is proportional to capacitance and inversely proportional to transconductance, which again results in an inverted-U shape curve for AC current gain.

The result is that the output impedance of anything that's based on transistors, and especially a voltage follower, is going to depend on output current, no exceptions. At low output current you can expect low transconductance which means higher output impedance.

The output impedance of the output stage of an amplifier causes a voltage drop: applying ohm's law, it is the product of its output impedance and output current flowing through it. If output impedance depends a lot on current, then this creates a form of crossover distortion, adding error voltage as current varies, especially near zero current.

In class-AB amplifiers this is mitigated by adding idle current to the output stage, so at least one transistor always run at high enough bias current to keep its transconductance healthy. There is a compromise (design choice) between wasted power due to bias current and distortion.

On the internal schematics of your opamp, I don't see any circuit to set an idle current in the output stage. This results in the absolute minimum idle current for the opamp. This is nice for running on batteries, but as a compromise you get large variations in output impedance as output current gets near zero.

If the signal is slow enough (low frequency) the high open loop gain of the opamp compensates for this: errors due to the output stage are reduced according to the amount of feedback available, which is the open loop gain divided by the in-circuit gain.

Open loop gain (and thus the amount of it available to correct this kind of crossover distortion) falls with frequency, so feedback is much less effective at correcting this kind of distortion when it operates on AC signals, say in the audio range. So this opamp would be absolutely terrible for a low distortion AC application (like audio). But for buffering low frequency or DC signals from sensors, which is its intended application, it's fine.